# Exporting Charts of Access to Image Format?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, graph, vba, export

I have created a chart in Access forms and exported it in Image Format. It's easily done, but the problem comes when after it, when I close the Form, It Shows a Pop-up message.

> "The operation on the Chart object failed.
>   The OLE server may not be registered.
>   To register the OLE server, reinstall it. "

Then I have done some change and the Code looks Like:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()     
  Dim grpApp As Graph.Chart 

  Set grpApp = Me.Graph1.Object     
  grpApp.Export "C:\Graph1.jpg", "JPEG"     
  Me.Graph1.Enabled = True    
  Me.Graph1.Locked = False    
  Set grpApp = Nothing     
  Me.Graph1.Action = acOLEClose     
End Sub
```

Now the problem is that after the export is done, the chart becomes bad, the fonts were big
and condensed and the bars looked short...

I'm really stuck..

Answer (score 0):

After trying various workarounds, I found pretty much the same question and a proper fix for the problem:

- Try unlocking the graph before the export, and restore the lock afterwards

> ```
> 'Unlock the control...
> Me!YourOLEChart.Locked = False
> Me!YourOLEChart.Enabled = True
>
> 'Do the actual export...
> Set oleGrf = Me!YourOLEChart.Object
> oleGrf.Export filename, "JPEG"
> Set oleGrf = Nothing
> Me!YourOLEChart.Action = acOLEClose
>
> 'Restore the lock...
> Me!YourOLEChart.Locked = True
> Me!YourOLEChart.Enabled = False
> ```

- Important: remember to set the Action acOLEClose to avoid the OLE server from crashing.

You are not alone—I had the same problem. On several runs of the form, after the export execution, the chart/graph/OLEFrame became wrong (on the form View), its format got changed and I hadn't known why.

Comment: No longer get OLE server crash but graph format is messed up next time form opens. Can only restore it by resizing chart.