# Save graph image from ms access when run as scheduled task

Tags: vba, ms-access

Can anyone help as to how to save a graph in a ms access form / report as an image, WHEN running it from a scheduled task?
No problem to do when running access from explorer as normal, and no problem to run access from a scheduled task, but have not been able to do both.

For saving charts as image see [Exporting Charts of Access to Image Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262698/exporting-charts-of-access-to-image-format)
This side of it is working fine, but when running as scheduled task it is not exported. (No issues with running other code when started from task schedule)

Comment: With *scheduled task* you mean the Windows scheduler? Does the task runs as System or as Regular user (as far as I know, Office cannot run as System)? Is Access started at all? Write a logfile to see what is happening, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/22663810/7599798

Comment: Works for me. Post your code.

Comment: Yes windows scheduled task. Yes access does start.
From logging can see that it fails on the
graphExp.Export "C:\Images\Graph11.jpg", "jpeg"
Does not get past this

Answer (score 0):

My code behind form to export graph from form:

```
Dim graphExp As Object
Set graphExp = Me.Graph11
graphExp.Export "C:\Images\Graph11.jpg", "jpeg"
```

Code is in Open event of form set to open by default when db opens. Then VBScript opens the db. Alternately, modify code for a general module (including opening the form) and VBScript can call that procedure.

```
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase "yourpath\yourdb.accdb"
accessApp.Run "Test"
accessApp.Quit
```